# Getting the error - "Error loading workspace: packages.Load error: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: no modules were found in the current workspace"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a go language code using VSCode. I have installed the go language on my system and also installed the required extension in VSCode for Go language. But this error message keeps showing up in the status bar :- "Error loading workspace: packages.Load error: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: no modules were found in the current workspace; see 'go help work'"

[This is the image of the code along with the error that is being shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC1u8.png)

I tried uninstalling the go language and also the extension for go language in VSCode and tried reinstalling it but to no avail. The problem still persists. What I can't understand is that the program is running just fine without showing any error messages and also the "PROBLEMS" section of VSCode doesn't show any problems. But still that error message is being shown in the status bar at the bottom of the page. Please help me to fix this issue.

[This is the image of the successful run of the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VNFt.png)

[This is the image of the problems section of VSCode showing no problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA96o.png)

[This is the image of the error that is being shown in the status bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that in the folder you opened with VS Code, there is a `go.work` file.

If you're just working on a simple module, you don't need to use `go work` at all. Make a new folder somewhere, copy your source `.go` files into it, and then do `go mod init` in that folder.  If you open that folder with VS Code, it should be happy.

The `go work` command is only needed if you're working on a module, and at the same time, making changes to some of its dependencies - it basically tells Go to use the local version of the dependencies instead of pulling them from their source repos.  In that scenario, you'd have a top-level folder where you've done `go work init`, and sub-folders that are either new modules (so you'd do `go mod init` in those sub-folders), or dependencies that you've cloned.  Either way, you tell Go to use them with the `go work use` command, e.g. `go work use ./mymodule` or `go work use ./somethingcloned`